# domain name prefix 'www'

Tags: domain-name

In a domain name, mostly started with prefix 'www'.is it used like a standard? ifnot, let me know, why?

Comment: www. is deprecated - http://no-www.org/

Comment: @dalle — No it isn't. https://www.yes-www.org/

Answer (score 2):

`www` stands for `world wide web`. Many web addresses begin with www, because of the long-standing practice of naming Internet hosts (servers) according to the services they provide.

[WWW prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web#WWW_prefix)

Answer (score 1):

A FQDN starting with "www." is used, by convention, for the machine hosting the primary website for a domain.

These days, where websites are more important then they were in the early days of the Internet, it is conventional to also run a webserver on the main machine for the domain (i.e. example.com rather than www.example.com) (these are usually the same machine) and redirect from one to the other.